# Find a value in a table query

Tags: jquery, html

in this example I don't find the value in the div `.copy_song`
I tried `closest`, `find`, `prevAll` but nothing.
Every time it returns an `undefined`.

```
<table id="canzoni_player" class="display responsive dataTable no-footer" cellspacing="0" width="100%" role="grid" aria-describedby="canzoni_player_info" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%;">
<tbody>
<tr role="row" class="odd">
  <td class="sorting_1">40044</td>
  <td>TITLE</td>
  <td>TITLE</td>
  <td>
    <div class="copy_song btn btn-danger" rel="40044">Copia &gt;&gt;<input type="hidden" value="40044" id="valore_codice">
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>108</td>
  <td>2016</td>
  <td>2A</td>
  <td>8</td>
  <td>
    <div class="click_play start">button
                        <input type="hidden" value="TEST">
        </div>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr role="row" class="odd">
  <td class="sorting_1">40045</td>
  <td>TITLE 2</td>
  <td>TITLE 2</td>
  <td>
    <div class="copy_song btn btn-danger" rel="40044">Copia &gt;&gt;<input type="hidden" value="40044" id="valore_codice">
    </div>
      </td>
  <td>120</td>
  <td>2018</td>
  <td>3A</td>
  <td>9</td>
  <td>
    <div class="click_play start">button
                        <input type="hidden" value="TEST2">
        </div>
 </td>
</tr>



</tbody>
</table>

$(document).ready(function() {

 $('#canzoni_player tbody .click_play').click(function(){
var canzone=$(this).find('input[type="hidden"]').val();

 var canzone_player=$(this).closest().find('.copy_song').attr('rel');

alert (canzone_player);
});

});
```

So I can find the value in `.copy_song` div only in this table row, because every row has a different value, so I have to use the reference (`this`)
I want to find the 'rel' value of div .copy_song, in my case if I click on the button I have to find '40044' and if I click on the other button I have to find '40045'

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/68954/)

Comment: What are you trying to find? Please edit your question, it's unclear what you're asking

Comment: I want to find the 'rel' value of div .copy_song, in my case if I click on the button I have to find '40044' and if I click on the other button I have to find '40045'

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want to find out the value of the `rel` attribute in each of your `div`s

Comment: @JBDouble05 yes, the 'rel' value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to look first for the parent `tr` with [parents()](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) and then find the `.copy_song` element

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#canzoni_player tbody .click_play').click(function() {
    var canzone = $(this).find('input[type="hidden"]').val();
    var codice_titolo_canzone = $(this).parents('tr').find('.copy_song').find('input[type="hidden"]').val();

    alert(codice_titolo_canzone);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 5px;
}

label {
  font-weight: bold;
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 20em
}

p {
  margin: 1em 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="canzoni_player" class="display responsive dataTable no-footer" cellspacing="0" width="100%" role="grid" aria-describedby="canzoni_player_info" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%;">
  <tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td class="sorting_1">40056</td>
      <td>TEXT</td>
      <td>TEXT</td>
      <td>
        <div class="copy_song btn btn-danger" rel="40056">Copia &gt;&gt;<input type="hidden" value="40056" id="valore_codice">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>64</td>
      <td>2017</td>
      <td>6A</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>
        <div class="click_play start">button
          <input type="hidden" value="test">
        </div>
      </td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi, I have more tr elements if find the same value

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pettedemon/xpvt214o/757644/ if I have more tr it didn't find the relative value

Comment: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/pettedemon/xpvt214o/757644/) it's all right thanks, in my code I set the same value sorry

Answer (score 1):

Change `$(this).closest().find('.copy_song')` to

```
$(this).parents('tr').find('.copy_song')
```

Selects the parent `tr` first.

Comment: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/pettedemon/xpvt214o/757644/) it's all right thanks, in my code I set the same value sorry